# Kendo UI grid editor dropdown "Can't find variable" error

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo UI grid that uses two dropdown menus as part of inline editing back to a CRUD service.  One of the dropdowns works just fine, but the second is causing errors even though I believe that it is coded exactly the same way.  Can someone lend a fresh pair of eyes to this?  Perhaps I am missing something really dumb, but I have been mucking with it since last night and have been unable to find where my mistake is.  Additionally, maybe unrelated, but when I try to use the grid, I am now getting a new error when trying to drag one of the columns to the header area to group rows based on it.  Here is my code for the grid:

```
var userAccessControlDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
transport: {
  read: {
    url: 'UAC_CRUD_service',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json'
  },
  update: {
    url: 'UAC_CRUD_service_update',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json'
  },
  destroy: {
    url: 'UAC_CRUD_service_destroy',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json'
  },
  create: {
    url: 'UAC_CRUD_service_create',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json'
  },
  parameterMap: function(options,operation) {
    if(operation !== 'read' && options.models) {
      return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
    }
  }
},
batch: true,
pageSize: 25,
schema: {
  model: {
    id: 'id',
    fields: {
      username:      {type: 'text'},
      database:      {type: 'text'},
      permissions:   {type: 'text', defaultValue: { permissions: 'ro'}}
    }
  }
}});
var userAccessControlGrid = $('#user_permissions_grid').kendoGrid({
dataSource: userAccessControlDS,
pageable: true,
width: '380px',
toolbar: ['create'],
columns: [
  {field: 'username',title: 'User Name'},
  {field: 'database', title: 'Database', nullable: true, editor: function(container,options) {
    $('<input required data-text-field="path" data-value-field="path" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendoDropDownList({
      dataTextField: 'path',
      dataValueField: 'path',
      autoBind: false,
      optionLabel: 'Select',
      index: 0,
      dataSource: {
        transport: {
          read: {
            url: 'list_databases',
            dataType: 'json'
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }, template: "#= database.path #"},
  {field: 'permissions', title: 'Permissions', nullable: true, editor: function(container,options){
    $('<input required data-text-field="permissionsString" data-value-field="permissions" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendoDropDownList({
      dataTextField: 'permissionsString',
      dataValueField: 'permissions',
      autoBind: false,
      optionLabel: 'Select',
      index: 0,
      dataSource: [
        {permissionsString: 'Read-Only',permissions: 'ro'},
        {permissionsString: 'Read-Write',permissions: 'rw'}
      ]
    });
  }, template: "#= permissions.permissionsString #"},
  {command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;" }
],
editable: 'inline',
groupable: true}).data('kendoGrid');
```

The errors I am getting for the variable are "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: database.

For the drag and drop grouping I am seeing a syntax error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Object'. Expected either a closing ']' or a ',' following an array element."

Comment: Is `database` property a part of the model?

Comment: dont use 'database' as your field name, its already reserved. Use some other name for that column

Comment: Is there anywhere in the documentation that shows reserved/special keywords that must not be use?  I tried changing it to 'databases', because I wanted to rule that out as an issue, but it made no difference, so I assumed my error was elsewhere.

I will try changing It to something entirely different.